# (JS) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I was doing the first exercise in the JavaScript30 challenge ([JS Drum kit](https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/tree/master/01%20-%20JavaScript%20Drum%20Kit)) and I encountered my first error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
>       at removeTransition (trial.html:73)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="65" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="68" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="70" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">openhat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="71" class="key">
      <kbd>G</kbd>
      <span class="sound">boom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="72" class="key">
      <kbd>H</kbd>
      <span class="sound">ride</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="74" class="key">
      <kbd>J</kbd>
      <span class="sound">snare</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="75" class="key">
      <kbd>K</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="76" class="key">
      <kbd>L</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tink</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>

<script>
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`)
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`)
    if(!audio) return; // stop function from running
    audio.currentTime = 0; // rewind to the start
    audio.play();
    key.classList.add('playing');

});

function removeTransition(e) {
    if(e.propertyName !== 'transform') return; // skip it if it's not a transform
    this.classList.remove('playing');
}

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I've been doing it side by side with the video tutorial, typing it againg but I still don't get why it isn't working for me.

Comment: You appear to be calling `addEventListener` on the global context (ie `window`). You probably mean to use `key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition)`

Comment: Oh sorry... I misread it! Took down the comment...

Comment: @Phil but I am..  keys.forEach(key => addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));

Comment: @Jimdiew read my comment again... `keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener(...))`

Comment: @Phil my bad! Thank you so much